# Backup keychains from hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, backup, crash, keychain

During the installation of Yosemite, I got locked out due to my hard drive having some errors.  Thankfully I had a Windows partition and am able to access my files.

However, how do I backup my Keychain keys when I only have access to the files?  I am specifically trying to backup my developer private key.

Comment: it's in ~/Library/Keychains/ though I'm not sure how that would work as a copy via windows. No backup?

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to copy the Keychains directory

```
Finder -> Go -> Go to folder... -> /Library/Keychains
```

or something like

```
cp -r /Library/Keychains ~/Desktop/MyKeychainsBackup [in terminal window]
```

However, the Keychains is saved with iCloud; you don't really need to make a local backup.

Comment: So my developer private key is going to be backed up with iCloud too?